# Cannot run multiple files when connected to Server in VSCode Python

Tags: python, networking

I am trying to test connections to a server from a network. I have 2 seperate files; server.py and network.py.

My server.py works as it says "Server Started" but when I try to run network.py to connect to the server, it does not let me run it. I am doing this in VSCode so I don't know if its a software bug.

I have provided the server.py code and network.py code (They are in the same workspace and directory) and for privacy I have hidden my IP address

**Server.py:**

```
       import socket
    from _thread import *
    import sys
    
    
    server = "XXXXXX" # server address on LAN
    
    port = 5555 # 5555 is an open safe port for use
    
    socket_x = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # .AF_INET allows sokcet to communicate with addresses
    # SOCK_STREAM IS USED BY TCP SERVER WHICH ALLOWS DEVICES TO TRANSMIT DATA TO ONE ANOTHER
    
    
    try: # check for socket errors 
        socket_x.bind((server, port)) # creating server
    
    except socket.error as e:
        str(e)
    
    socket_x.listen(2) # allows for connections (2 people can connect)
    
    
    print("Waiting for Connection, Test Server Started")
    
    
    def threaded_client(conn):
    
        conn.send(str.encode("Connected"))
        
        reply = ""
        while True:
            try:
                data = conn.recv(2048)
                reply = data.decode("utf-8")
    
                if not data:
                    print("Disconnected")
                    break
                else: # if there is data
                    print("Recieved: ", reply)
                    print("Sending: ",  reply)
                
                conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
            
            except:
                break
    
            print("Lost connection")
            conn.close()
    
    while True: # continuosly looking for connections
        conn, address = socket_x.accept() # accept any incoming connections and store into variables
        print("Connected to:", address)
    
       # start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, ))
    
        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, ))
```

**Network.py:**

```
    import socket

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        self.server = "XXXXXX" # will always be the same
        self.port = 5555
        self.address = (self.server, self.port)
        self.id = self.connect()

        print(self.id)

    def connect(self):

        try:  # trying to connect
            self.client.connect(self.address)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass


n = Network()
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: maybe it is normal behavior- maybe it can run only one script. Usually projects have only one script to start and in some IDEs project has assigned one script to start. OR maybe it needs to run second script in special way. Or maybe you will have to run second script manually without VSCode using standard terminal/console/cmd.exe in system

Comment: @furas Thank you for your answer. I have found that I have to run network.py first since server.py was already running in order to connect